# Sendgrid unsubscribe tag getting converted to htmlentites

Tags: html-email, sendgrid

I am having a weird issue with Sendgrid's Group Unsubscribe Substitution Tag. I have inserted the tag `<%asm_group_unsubscribe_url%>` in the html mode directly, saved and it works well. When I go to the design mode and come back to the html mode the tags are getting converted to html entities like `&lt;%asm_group_unsubscribe_url%&gt;` and not working. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Hello, since this is a question about a UI rather than directly about programming, I suggest reaching out to SendGrid support.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the < and >

It's not an HTML tag, it's just template code so you only need %whatever_unsub_url% and it should work as long as the name matches up with what you've set in your SendGrid settings. It's actually just printing the link, so you can do something like

```
<a href="%sendgrid_unsub_url%">Click to unsubscribe.</a>
```